# Array out of bounds exception

Tags: java, parsing, arraylist

I'm trying to parse a text file that looks like:

```
1     400.0     -1.6533271     5.7718643 
2     401.0     -1.6596413     5.7751263 
3     402.0     -1.6656540     5.7781345 
4     403.0     -1.6713679     5.7808704 
5     404.0     -1.6767864     5.7833152
```

So I've made the following method to get each of those values separately:

```
void parseFile(String filepath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    FileReader filereader = new FileReader(filepath);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(filereader);
    String s;

    while ((s = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] tab = s.split("   ");
        double number = parseDouble(tab[0]);
        double lambda = parseDouble(tab[1]);
        double re = parseDouble(tab[2]);
        double im = parseDouble(tab[3]);

    }

}

private double parseDouble(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
        return 0.0;
    } else {
        return Double.parseDouble(s);
    }
}
```

And when I'm trying to use `lambda` value (to add it to my `ArrayList`):

```
mylist.add(lambda);
```

I get an exception in line where `lambda` is declared:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you searched google for the title of your question, what did you find? Or when you stepped through your code with a debugger, what did you find?

Comment: Are you sure you will get 4 values when you split by ```"   "```??? A better idea is to iterate tab, but not to access values by index.

Comment: How are you initializing mylist arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a string by any whitespace, like space or tab, a better way to do it is:

```
myString.split("\\s+");
```

In your example, the whitespaces among columns could be spaces, tabs, or mixture of both. `String[] tab = s.split("   ");` could results in only one element in variable `tab`. In this case, when you try to access the second element, you will get OutOfIndex error cause there is only one element in tab.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of formatting, but your data is separated by 5 spaces, you are splitting by 3 spaces. To avoid cases like that, it might make sense to use tabs or a regex like " {5}", stating the actual number of spaces instead of typing it manually.